# Adding individual test cases to a suite in utPLSQL

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have a test package containing 6 test cases. I want to build 2 suites:
1st containing test1, test2
2nd containing test3, test4, test 5

As per documentation we can add only entire test package to a suite, but not individual test cases. Also, I dont want to segregate packages based on suite requirement as they are for same group, but different functionality.

Any suggestions on this will be greatly appreciated. And, do feel free to let me know if my current understanding is wrong. Thanks in advance. Adding some sample code:

```
CREATE PACKAGE ut_test_pkg 
IS BEGIN 
PROCEDURE ut_test1;
   PROCEDURE ut_test2;
   PROCEDURE ut_test3;
   PROCEDURE ut_test4;
   PROCEDURE ut_test5; 
END;
 /
```

Now test1 and test2 are logically 1 test case and test3-5 another. I can do like :

```
begin 
utplsql.test ('test_pkg', recompile_in => FALSE, subprogram_in => 'test1');         utplsql.test ('test_pkg', recompile_in => FALSE, subprogram_in => 'test2'); 
end; 
/
```

But adding it to suite adds to simplicity. And it can simply run that suite for clubbing test1,test2 and test3-5.

On running individually, I get output like::
Success
test 1 <50 more lines>
Failure
test 2 <50 more lines>

I have close to 100 checks so gap between test result is quite large, and user have to scroll a lot. I am looking to add a heading which says final result at the top, like in test suites they do, where out put is like

SUITE FAILURE
Success
test 1 <50 more lines>
Failure
test 2 <50 more lines>

Comment: Post your code and give an example how you want

Comment: Thanks Xing for your assistance. Added Comment was difficult to read, I have updated original post. Hope it helps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like I found a viable and pretty straight forward solution solution for my query. I simply need need to properly specify the subprogram section during test run. 
So, first all test cases which I need to club must contain a common string which I can use to search::

```
CREATE PACKAGE ut_test_pkg 
IS BEGIN 
   PROCEDURE ut_abc_test1;
   PROCEDURE ut_abc_test2;
   PROCEDURE ut_def_test3;
   PROCEDURE ut_def_test4;
   PROCEDURE ut_def_test5; 
END;
 /
```

While executing I do it like::

```
begin
  utplsql.test ('test_pkg', recompile_in => FALSE, subprogram_in => '%abc%');
end
/
begin
  utplsql.test ('test_pkg', recompile_in => FALSE, subprogram_in => '%def%');
end;
/
```

This will run test case containing abc in first case and consolidated result [Success/Failue] is shown at the top of the dbms_output. So, user will not have to scroll for checking test case of each and every test. Similarly, for def in 2nd run.

Thanks all for your help on this.